# Similarities between Latin Letters

Tags: alphabet

Have there been any studies done into the similarity between individual latin letters? I'm hoping for something (preferably with letters in Arial font) where a letter has been given and the chance of other letters being confused with it is the result. Absolutely ideally the result would be something like this, where columns are the letter presented and rows are the letter returned (numbers completely made up):

<> A <> B <> C

A -.-- 0.43 0.32

B 0.43 -.-- 0.44

C 0.33 0.23 -.--

I've tried looking myself and am wondering if I'm looking for the wrong thing. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

And, predictably, after spending half a week looking for it, I found it 10 minutes after asking for help. For those that may need it in future:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225784495_Theoretical_analysis_of_an_alphabet_confusion_matrix

Provides a confusion matrix for letters given a stimulus in 'Table 1'

Answer (score 0):

Well, take the word "Caius" , which is also seen as "Gaius" -- to show the difference in pronunciation from other uses the hook was put on the 'C" and was born the "G"
The "J" came in a consonantal "I" and the "V" as consonantal 'U" -- which by the way shows that the double-you "W" is a double 'U"